# Strange assembly code generated after compiling

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction, compilation

I'm just trying to plus 0x3C but the compiler is converting it to 0x0F0. Why??

This is the kernel32_base declaration that is passed as argument to the function:

> DWORD* kernel32_base

And here the C code and the desassembled code:

```
DWORD PE_shift=NULL;
00DB212E  mov         dword ptr [PE_shift],0  
    PE_shift = *(kernel32_base + 0x3C); //60=3Ch
00DB2135  mov         eax,dword ptr [kernel32_base]  
00DB2138  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax+0F0h]  ; <-----------------
00DB213E  mov         dword ptr [PE_shift],ecx
```

From where is that 0F0h coming from? It should be a 0x3C right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `DWORD` is a four byte type.  Your C code says load the `0x3C`'th 4-byte quantity after the base pointer.  `4` times `0x3C` is `0xF0`.  If you want to get the `DWORD` at byte offset `0x3C`, then it needs to be:

```
PE_shift = *(DWORD*)((char*)kernel32_base + 0x3C);
```

Comment: mmmmm interesting. How should I do it then to just plus 0x3C to the address stored in kernel32_base? Thanks

Comment: Sweet! Works great. PD: Two negatives votes already?? :( Thank you

Comment: I have to wait 3 minutes. I'll accept it as soon as i can ;) thanks again